# projecting a RegionProduct into 3D space

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

Apparently, `RegionProduct` should allow you to generate convolution-generated shapes. For instance, take a 1D curve and a sphere, and the region product I would expect to obtain is the 1D curve **thickened** by the sphere shape. But `RegionProduct` of a 1D curve in 3D and a 3D sphere is actually in 6D space.

Is there some way to obtain the convolution region I just described?

**Edit** the logical operation that I would want to do is a morphological [Dilation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html), but when passing a geometrical region to this function, it complains that it *"is neither a rectangular array nor an image"*

Comment: That sounds like a morphological filter, like dilation.

Comment: can you provide a reference or an example? I can't find anything on Google or Wolfram portal

Comment: What keywords did you search? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology.  Much of the literature is focused on 2D and image processing.

Comment: the point is that I can't find a way to take two regions and make this new region with them

Comment: when passing a geometric region to this operation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html it complains that it **'is neither a rectangular array nor an image'**

Comment: In this context of regions in Euclidean space, this operation is more commonly known as the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition). There doesn't appear to be a built-in method for it. If [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html) accepted two regions as input, you could have done `TransformedRegion[r1, r2, Function[{p1, p2}, p1 + p2]]`, but that doesn't work right now.

Comment: I thought also to use a `GeometricTransform` with a projection matrix on the six-dimensional `RegionProduct` result and take a tridimensional slice (basically passing a 6x6 matrix with ones on the first three diagonal elements and zero on the other 3), but for some reason `GeometricTransform` is arbitrarily limited to tridimensional spaces